# Why I cannot store into a variable the return result of an logic expression in C code?

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I have a strange behavior of a small piece of C code.
I want to store the result of a boolean expression in a variable but it seems not to work.

Following the code:

```
 #define rtCP_Constant_Value_fklq (uint8_t) 1 //Simulink const
 #define rtCP_Constant_Value (uint8_t) 0 //Simulink const

 uint16_t rtb_tobit;
 volatile unsigned char rtb_y;
 uint8_t asr_ena_=14;
 rtb_tobit = (1 << rtCP_Constant_Value_fklq);

 uint8_t temp = ((uint8_t)rtb_tobit) & asr_ena_;
 rtb_y = (temp !=(rtCP_Constant_Value));
```

I have tested this snippet of code with two compilers, Renesas SH 9_4_1 and gcc-arm non-eabi in an Nucleo eval board.
In both of them the variable `rtb_y` is always zero.
The debugger shows that the expression `(temp !=(rtCP_Constant_Value))` is true but I cannot understand why, the variable `rtb_y` is always equal to zero.

Could someone explain me why? Is this strange behaviour because of C standards, which I used?

Comment: If you enable more warnings when building (add at least the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` flags, possibly `-pedantic`), the compiler doesn't complain?

Comment: I don't know about these boards but a `volatile` variable is allowed to change its value in an implementation-defined way: it's possible that on this platform, setting it *seems* to do nothing because it's allowed to change itself back to zero immediately (perhaps it detects it is set and does something else as an interrupt?).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @Leushenko I dont use interrupts and I used the volatile only to avoid the optimization.

Comment: Did you try printing the values of `rtb_y` or use it after the assignment or did you only look in the debugger? Sometimes the debugger might fool you.

Comment: @Gerhardh Both :(, print and debugger.

Comment: Remove `;` from the `#define`s.  Example `#define rtCP_Constant_Value_fklq ((uint8_t) 1)`.   xmaze, Does that work for you?

Comment: Once you remove the `;` my compiler ends up with `rtb_y = 1`

Comment: After seeing the ; in the defines now, how can this even compile?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow You are write, I tested again and I found the problem. It was optimization issue of the compiler. Now it is working also for me.

Comment: @Gerhardh Sorry, the `;` is only an error in my message not in the original C Code.

Answer (score 0):

It is a really bad idea to use macros in the way you are using them. You need to be very careful, generally, to use parenthesis in the right places. Also you should not include the ; in the macro. For example, this is better:

```
#define rtCP_Constant_Value_fklq ((uint8_t) 1) //Simulink const
```

However, it is not really possible to offer any more help for your question than this, because your example will not compile, due to the inclusion of the ;. If you update the question with code that compiles, it may be possible to help further.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the syntax error in the message, I can compile this code and debugg. I found the error las nicht. It was an optimization issue of the compiler.